# Increment map key in react js when adding a record to a form

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to add a record to a form in react, I can add only one record right now but would like to make it more dynamic and therefore I need to increment map id key when a record is added in order to add more records in the future

```
 if (length == 0) {
          this.state.records.push({
            id: 1,
            input: this.state.input,
            input2: this.state.input2
          });
        }

        renderTableData() {
      if (this.props.records.length > 0) {
        return this.props.records.map((record, index) => {
          const { id, input, input2 } = record;
          return (
            <tr key={id}>
              <td>{input}</td>
              <td>{input2}</td>

            </tr>
          );
        });
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Comment: `this.state.records.push` should probably be a call to `this.setState`. Can you elaborate further on what the issue is here? I don't really follow what you're trying to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize your **`state`** by your **`props`** first, where this.props.records is an object of array type

```
state = {
    records: this.props.records
  };
```

Now you can add a arrow function to push your input data to your **`state`**

```
handleAddNew = () => {
    let { records } = this.state;

    records.push({
      id: records ? records.length + 1 : 0,
      input: this.state.input,
      input2: this.state.input2
    });

    this.setState({ records });
  };
```

And call that function on a button click

```
<button onClick={this.handleAddNew}>Add New</button>
```

Finally you have to use state instead of props like **`this.props.records`** by **`this.state.records`** on your code